# transactions signed always reverted

Tags: transactions, web3j, java

I don't know how to send a signed transaction against a method payable in Ganache, can someone help me???
When I call the method in Remix it works fine but from Java I get the Hash of the transaction but it always with response "VM Exception while processing transaction: revert".
The wrapper is:

```
public RemoteFunctionCall<TransactionReceipt> participar(BigInteger weiValue) {
        final Function function = new Function(
                FUNC_PARTICIPAR, 
                Arrays.<Type>asList(), 
                Collections.<TypeReference<?>>emptyList());
        return executeRemoteCallTransaction(function, weiValue);
    }
```

The java code is:

```
public Main(){
        try {
            web3j = Web3j.build(new HttpService("http://127.0.0.1:7545")); //local ganache 
            credentials = Credentials.create("896d708b0e071ee853......");
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, Exception{
  Main test = new Main();
  Loteria contract = test.loadContract(); //Load the deployed MyContract contract
  ...
  Loteria contract = test.loadContract();
  System.out.println("Precio: " + contract.precio().send()); // work ok
  ...
  Function function = new Function("participar", 
                        Arrays.<Type>asList(), 
                        Collections.<TypeReference<?>>emptyList());
  String encodedFunction = FunctionEncoder.encode(function);
  String contrato = "0x6080604052604051610604380380610604833981810160405260408110156100265......";
  BigInteger nonce = test.getTransactionCount(test.ADDRESS_CUENTA);
  BigInteger valueParticipar = BigInteger.valueOf(100);
  RawTransaction rawTransaction = RawTransaction.createTransaction(nonce, GAS_PRICE, GAS_LIMIT, test.CONTRACT_ADDRESS, valueParticipar, new String(Hex.encode(contrato.getBytes())) +   encodedFunction);             
  byte[] signedMessage = TransactionEncoder.signMessage(rawTransaction, test.credentials);
  String hexValue = Numeric.toHexString(signedMessage);
  EthSendTransaction ethSendTransaction = test.web3j.ethSendRawTransaction(hexValue).sendAsync().get();
  String transactionHash = ethSendTransaction.getTransactionHash();
...
```

The getters for global scope variables work fine.

Thank you so much.

Environment:
Web3j version. core 4.6.3
Java 8
Operating System Windows
Ganache

Comment: you need to get the string of the REVERT failure, it is reported on the return value of the call

Comment: I'm not a java developer but it seems you are concatenating the contract bytecode `contrato` with the function encoded, that doesn't look right. Try passing only the encoded function call.

Answer (score 0):

I got to fix it. I had several erros.
I have used the example to solved it https://github.com/web3j/web3j/blob/master/integration-tests/src/test/java/org/web3j/protocol/scenarios/HumanStandardTokenIT.java.

Thanks you